How do I erase the data after sending a notification with data?
I send the user to the home page like normal, it has an event listener with data to send them to another screen. Then my router goes back to the home page and the user gets stuck in an infinite loop getting sent to the notification data and it sends them on an infinite loop.
using:
"expo": "~51.0.17",
"expo-notifications": "~0.28.9",


I have a scheduled notification that repeats on a trigger
    async function scheduleWeeklyNotification() {
        try {
          const notificationScheduled = await AsyncStorage.getItem('weeklyTopNotificationScheduled');
      
          if (notificationScheduled !== 'true') {
            await Notifications.scheduleNotificationAsync({
              content: {
                title: "Flavrite",
                body: "Here's some trending new products for you to rate, review ... and hopefully taste.",
                data: { screen: 'WeeklyTop' },
              },
              trigger: {
                // seconds: 5, // 5 seconds
                weekday: 7, // 1 is Sunday, 7 is Saturday
                hour: 11, // 11 AM
                minute: 0,
                repeats: true // This ensures it repeats every week
              },
            });
      
            await AsyncStorage.setItem('weeklyTopNotificationScheduled', 'true');
          }
        } catch (error) {
          console.error('Error scheduling notification:', error);
        }
    }

and then in my useEffect I have it going to a different page
    useEffect(() => {
        registerForPushNotificationsAsync()
        .then((token) => setExpoPushToken(token ?? ''))
        .catch((error) => setExpoPushToken(`${error}`));

        notificationListener.current =
            Notifications.addNotificationReceivedListener((notification) => {
                setNotification(notification);
            });

        responseListener.current =
            Notifications.addNotificationResponseReceivedListener((response) => {
                const data = response.notification.request.content.data;
                if (data.screen == 'WeeklyTop') {
                    navigation.navigate('WeeklyTop');
                }
                if (data.product) {
                    navigation.navigate('ShowFlava', { item: data.id });
                }
                console.log("Notification response:", response.notification.request.content.data.screen);
            });
    
            return () => {

                  Notifications.removeNotificationSubscription(notificationListener.current);
         
                  Notifications.removeNotificationSubscription(responseListener.current);
              };
      }, []);

So after the navigation goes to WeeklyTop, it is a swiper that then resets the navigation to the home page where this runs again and will send that user back to the Weekly Top screen
Thus repeating the infinite loop. Even if I move the navigate to another screen, it's still stuck on an infinite loop.
